Is it true that ${M^G}[2]={M[2]}^G$ where $^G$ denotes Galois fixed part？
Let $G$ be a group and $M$ be a $G$-module.

Is it true that ${M^G}[2]={M[2]}^G$ where $^G$ denotes Galois fixed
part and $M[2]=\{m\in M\mid 2m=0\}$?

My try : Consider $0\to M[2]\to M$. Because $0\to M[2]^G\to M^G$ is also exact (in other words, taking $G$ invariant is left exact)and any elements in $M[2]^G$ is killed by $2$, so $M[2]^G\subset M^G[2]$ holds.
Let prove the other inclusion,$M^G[2]\subset M[2]^G$.
Take $m\in M^G[2]$.$m$ is killed by $2$ and $G$ invariant, so $m\in M[2]^G$.
For my purpose, $M[2]^G\subset M^G[2]$ is just needed, and $M[2]^G\subset M^G$ is quite clear, but I'm a bit afraid that I made a mistake to conclude $M[2]^G\subset M^G[2]$ because I have never seen such a inclusion and equality.
In summary,
Is this kind of equality ${M^G}[2]={M[2]}^G$ known or are there some counterexamples?

Is there a question hiding somewhere? This is not a "here's my proof, check it for me" site.

Yes, this proof is fine, or,  just in words, both of these modules are just the set of things in $M$ that are killed by the number $2$ and fixed by the action of $G$. (The observation you made about "even order" doesn't matter.)

@ArturoMagidin your comment seems a bit uncharitable to me. Even before the edits, there was a clear question, namely the highlighted portion beginning with "Is it true that...". Moreover, some MSE users aggressively vote to close posts where the question does not contain the poster's attempts at solving the problem. Finally, there is in fact a "solution-verification" tag, so I don' think it's fair to say that questions asking for proof verification are off-topic on the site. The question has since improved, and your feedback likely helped, but I think there were nicer ways to express it.

@AlexWertheim 1. The highlighted version looks like a prompt, not a question from the OP. 2. Yes, there is a "solution-verification" tag. And that tag's description says: ""Is my proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so. " which means that simply posting a proof, with or without a tag, (the tag was added by someone else, btw), and just waiting for a "yes, that's right" is in fact not suitable for the site. 3. I neither downvoted nor voted to close.

...4.  finally, the OP has been around (4 years), and has posted almost 600 questions, so the expectations should be both known and clear.
